# Powershell.Replace next string after matching

Tags: string, powershell, replace, match

I have listing.lst containning thousand lines. I need to replace one line which is dynamicly changes and position from end and start of file is also changing.
But there is constant string  "a","a" (there are several of them, i need last one)from which if i will go below by two lines i can find **target** line which must be chaged.

```
$log = 'c:\rep\listing.lst'
$match = '"a","a"'
$string = Select-String $match $log | ForEach-Object {$_.LineNumber + 1} | Select-Object -Last 1
(Get-Content $log)[$string]
```

I was able to find this string , but can't understand how i can change this **target** string to for example '"on"'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I build awhile back to find and replace strings in text files. At a minimum, pass in the FilePath, the string you'd like to find and the string to replace it and you're golden:

```
Find-InTextFile -FilePath C:\MyFile.txt -Find '"a","a"' -Replace 'on'

function Find-InTextFile
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Performs a find (or replace) on a string in a text file or files.
    .EXAMPLE
        PS> Find-InTextFile -FilePath 'C:\MyFile.txt' -Find 'water' -Replace 'wine'

        Replaces all instances of the string 'water' into the string 'wine' in
        'C:\MyFile.txt'.
    .EXAMPLE
        PS> Find-InTextFile -FilePath 'C:\MyFile.txt' -Find 'water'

        Finds all instances of the string 'water' in the file 'C:\MyFile.txt'.
    .PARAMETER FilePath
        The file path of the text file you'd like to perform a find/replace on.
    .PARAMETER Find
        The string you'd like to replace.
    .PARAMETER Replace
        The string you'd like to replace your 'Find' string with.
    .PARAMETER UseRegex
        Use this switch parameter if you're finding strings using regex else the Find string will
        be escaped from regex characters
    .PARAMETER NewFilePath
        If a new file with the replaced the string needs to be created instead of replacing
        the contents of the existing file use this param to create a new file.
    .PARAMETER Force
        If the NewFilePath param is used using this param will overwrite any file that
        exists in NewFilePath.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'NewFile')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf' })]
        [string[]]$FilePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Find,

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Replace,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$UseRegex,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'NewFile')]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path ($_ | Split-Path -Parent) -PathType 'Container' })]
        [string]$NewFilePath,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'NewFile')]
        [switch]$Force
    )
    begin
    {
        $SystemTempFolderPath = Get-SystemTempFolderPath
        if (!$UseRegex.IsPresent)
        {
            $Find = [regex]::Escape($Find)
        }
    }
    process
    {
        try
        {
            Write-Log -Message "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand) - BEGIN"
            foreach ($File in $FilePath)
            {
                if ($Replace)
                {
                    if ($NewFilePath)
                    {
                        if ((Test-Path -Path $NewFilePath -PathType 'Leaf') -and $Force.IsPresent)
                        {
                            Remove-Item -Path $NewFilePath -Force
                            (Get-Content $File) -replace $Find, $Replace | Add-Content -Path $NewFilePath -Force
                        }
                        elseif ((Test-Path -Path $NewFilePath -PathType 'Leaf') -and !$Force.IsPresent)
                        {
                            Write-Warning "The file at '$NewFilePath' already exists and the -Force param was not used"
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            (Get-Content $File) -replace $Find, $Replace | Add-Content -Path $NewFilePath -Force
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (Get-Content $File) -replace $Find, $Replace | Add-Content -Path "$File.tmp" -Force
                        Remove-Item -Path $File
                        Rename-Item -Path "$File.tmp" -NewName $File
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $Find
                }
            }
            Write-Log -Message "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand) - END"
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Log -Message "Error: $($_.Exception.Message) - Line Number: $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)" -LogLevel '3'
            Write-Log -Message "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand) - END"
            $false
        }
    }
}
```